# MySQL, linking data, constructing keys, insert into and update

Tags: mysql, transactions, foreign-keys, sql-update, lastinsertid

I have information relevant to specific groups of a table A. So I sort out these relevant groups and make an entry containing the group-specific information in a second table B. Up to this point no problem - even for me.

Now every single element of the group of A should be given the autoincrement id of the new entry in B. Seems to be a standard-procedure, but this is where my trouble starts since LAST_INSERT_ID() gives back only the id of the last entry in Table b (not really suprising for a function called LAST_INSERT) and I just can't get a combined "IF GROUP IN A, Insert "x" Into B and link to A by id" to work...

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a classic case for an AFTER INSERT trigger!

Comment: Is there no way to do the whole thing within one function/procedure?

Comment: Yup: The trigger. A trigger is nothing else than a function, that is called exactly once for every INSERT.

Comment: Well - I rearranged the whole structure. So I dont need a trigger anymore. Thanks!